# Error in saving form data to Google Spreadsheets Using PHP and the Google Docs API

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, google-docs-api, lampp

While saving my data in google spreadsheet using php via google doc api, i got the following error. How to include the required library files in php?

Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/ZendGdata-1.8.1/demos/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheet-ClientLogin.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/ZendGdata-1.8.1/demos/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheet-ClientLogin.php on line 25

Answer (score 0):

command to include file in php localhost is

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/path.php");
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$path = '/usr/lib/pear';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
?>
```

above I included the php file but it is not shown.